# i cannot view my crystal report in my simple web page

Tags: c#, mysql, crystal-reports

what seem to be the problem with my code? i cannot view it in my browser. i searched google and so but cannot find the answer. it is been 2 days already that i am looking for solutions. can anyone help thanks.

```
public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    string connectionString = "server=" + 
           ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Server"] + ";uid=" + 
           ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["User ID"] + ";pwd=" + 
           ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Password"] + ";database=" + 
           ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Database Name"] + 
           ";Command Timeout=28800;";    

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        EmpReport crystalReport = new EmpReport();
        dsEmp ds = GetData();
        crystalReport.SetDataSource(ds);
        this.CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = crystalReport;
        this.CrystalReportViewer1.RefreshReport();
    }

    private dsEmp GetData()
    {
        string query = "SELECT * FROM emp_table";
        MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query);
        MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter();
        cmd.Connection = con;
        da.SelectCommand = cmd;
        dsEmp ds = new dsEmp();
        da.Fill(ds, "DataTable1");
        return ds;
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not about the problem directly but in your sample you have an 8 hours connection timeout. This is some crazy high number you may want to put something more realistic because this can lock some precious resources on the server when an issue occur. The longest report to generate i have ever seen took about an hour and a half. And that was a major airline company doing luggage reporting over a large range of 2-3 months for all their flights.

Comment: can i delete the timeout?

Comment: If you put no timeout then the connection will stay open until either the client close the app or the server close. If the reports takes 10 seconds to generate that mean you need the connection opened for 10 seconds so making the connection timeout to something like 5 or 10 minutes is much more reasonable than 8 hours. The timeout is there for cases where there is an error that occur (other cases exist) and the thing runs forever so when it reach that timeout you set it will force it to stop and close the connection.

Comment: ok thank u. i am configuring my visual studio now.

Comment: There are a bunch of timeouts to consider. You've set the connection timeout to a large time interval.  But there's also the query timeout, the `CommandTimeout` property of the `MySqlCommand` object. Then there's the request `executionTimeout`.  To what values did you set those other two timeouts? Their defaults are 30s, and it's possible one or both are expiring before your `PageLoad` method completes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to display the Crystal Report by putting the 4_0_30319 folder found in the C://inetpub/wwwroot/aspnet_client/system_web into the root folder of my project. Also make it sure you got correct configurations in your project file (Web.config).